# Ubuntu 14.04 brightness issue

Tags: 14.04, brightness, battery

I have a Samsung laptop although I don't think this is relevant to the issue.

If I boot my laptop on **AC power**, all brightness functions work properly even if I subsequently remove it from the power.

If I boot my laptop on the **battery** ,brightness functions do not work at all even if I then plug in the power.

Can anyone shed any light on how to fix this?

I'm running **Ubuntu 14.04** with **Gnome-desktop**.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with brightness functions? there is a known issue with 14.04 brightness that the brightness is not remembered after reboot (always on max)... precise a little bit more your issue

Comment: @Neni Pretty sure there should be a comma between "battery" and "brightness".

Comment: I don't get what it means that battery functions don't work at all when booted on battery... does it mean that you can't adjust the brightness at all and/or the brightness is always on max/min or in state before boot... there are several possible issues with brightness in 14.04... precise it and maybe I can help...

Answer (score 0):

You lost me with mention of "battery brightness".  I don't know what that means.  Are you referring to screen brightness?  If it involves the screen, I can refer you to two command-line packages.  xrandr allows you to change screem resolution on the fly.  That works for desktops and laptops.  The package xbacklight only works for laptops.  That allows you to adjust your screen brightness on the fly.  If you want these settings to take place when you log in, make the commands part of a .profile script file in our $HOME folder.  This gives you an example:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    xrandr -s 1024x768
    xbacklight = 35
```